# What column definition should be used for Facebook application identifier

Tags: facebook

Is type and maximum size of Facebook's *application identifier* defined somewhere? What column type and constraints should be used to store it in SQL database? Text/varchar most probably but what maximum length? Is it digit only?

I can of course suspect that it will be not longer than let's say 32 digits/characters but I would like to be sure.

I have the same question regarding the *application secret* string. Is it possibly defined somewhere that it is 32 hex digits or I must assume it and possibly add some extra characters to be sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*What column definition should be used for Facebook application identifier*"

Application Id is a long/int64/BigInt